# How do I assign a value to variable before dispose()?

Tags: flutter

I would like to get the DateTime a variable to get the last time user exited the activity.
I used the deactive method which is called before dispose()

```
  @override
  void deactivate() {
    super.deactivate();
    
   
    var toLastSeen = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(DateTime.now().toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch);
 
    
    sl.get<Logger>().d(toLastSeen);
  }
```

I'm actually getting the data logged in my terminal when I exit the activity, But the problem is
when I open the activity again, the data is null? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your widget will be recreated after the dispose is called. I can give you a suggestion of storing the value in the session or you can use shared preferences for that. [shared_pref](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences). when the widget will be created you can call the shared pref and check if there is any value in it.